# Fill entire screen area with TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my application, I want to create a UI which will allow user to enter a header text and a content text. But the content text should fill the entire remaining area of the screen and the 'textBottomType' should be at the bottom of the screen.
How i can make sure that the 'textInputContent' will fill entire empty screen area? I tried different things with the UI and below is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_user_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_user_view">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp">
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/textInputHeaderInformation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Enter Your Header"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textInputHeader"
            android:padding="2dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputContentInformation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Your Content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textBottomType"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <ImageView android:src="@android:drawable/ic_popup_reminder" android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView android:text="Important Information"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:textColor="@color/winter"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Current Incorect view...
[image: Current UI view]

And this is what i want my view to be...
[image: Expected UI view]

Thanks,

*IamHuM*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set inputType property of Edittext to textMultiLine:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Comment: I made changes and this is how it looks. In this problem is the text below 'Enter Your Content' is a single line text but i want user to enter multi-line text in this. How i can allow user to enter multi-line text so that the whole screen can get filled with content text.

Comment: Added images for current UI and expected UI in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

I modified code as shown below. Thanks *Vivek* for your quick response.

```
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textInputContentInformation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Your Notes Content"
            android:inputType="text|textAutoComplete|textMultiLine|textLongMessage"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1000"
            />
```